# Trying to center buttons, TextView and Image View I’m creating Dynamically

Tags: android

I have a program that generates a rows of 4 buttons, in a horizontal container that gets added to a vertical container.

I cannot figure out how to have it so the buttons are centered, now they are aligns to the right hand side. Code:

```
for(int i=0; i<cGlobals.mNames.length; i+=2) {
    iSoundIdList[i]=soundPool.load(this, cGlobals.mSounds[i], 1);
    iSoundIdList[i+1]=soundPool.load(this, cGlobals.mSounds[i+1], 1);   

    // would like these views to all be centered    
    LinearLayout layout = new  LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(llp);

    favBut[i]=new ImageView(this);
    favBut[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.heartunselected);
    favBut[i].setId(defStartFavId+i);
    favBut[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    layout.addView(favBut[i]);

    Button but1=new Button(this);
    but1.setText( cGlobals.mNames[i]);
    but1.setWidth(120);
    layout.addView(but1);
    but1.setOnClickListener(this);
    but1.setId(defStartButId+i);

    TextView t=new TextView(this);
    t.setText("    ");
    layout.addView(t);

    favBut[i+1]=new ImageView(this);
    favBut[i+1].setImageResource(R.drawable.heartunselected);
    favBut[i+1].setId(defStartFavId+i+1);
    favBut[i+1].setOnClickListener(this);
    layout.addView(favBut[i+1]);

    t=new TextView(this);
    t.setText(" ");
    layout.addView(t);

    Button but2=new Button(this);
    but2.setText( cGlobals.mNames[i+1]);
    but2.setWidth(120);
    but2.setId(defStartButId+i+1);
    but2.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout.addView(but2);
    Container.addView(layout);
}
```

Comment: you are not using xmls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet will help

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(
    "sample_image", "drawable", getPackageName()));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
```